# Illustrating Forest Formula on Feynmp

Tags: feynmf, feynmp-auto

I'm trying to illustrate the Forest Formula for proving renormalizability as a final project for a course I'm taking. I need to find a way to put a rectangle with a dotted line (I can make do with it not being dotted) around subgraphs.

```
            \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,15)
                \fmfleft{i1,i2}
                \fmfright{f1,f2}
                \fmf{vanilla}{i1,v1}
                \fmf{vanilla}{i2,v1}
                \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v1,v2}
                \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v2,v1}
                \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v2,v3}
                \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v3,v2}
                \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v3,v4}
                \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v4,v3}
                \fmf{vanilla}{v4,f1}
                \fmf{vanilla}{v4,f2}
                \fmffreeze
                \fmf{phantom}{v1,v,v2}
                \fmfv{decor.shape=square,decor.filled=empty,decor.size=0.3w}{v}
            \end{fmfgraph*}
```

This is my best attempt so far. The issue is:

a) The shape is a square, is there anyway to get a rectangle that can snugly fit around the subgraph?
b) The shape is not transparent, you should be able to see the the subgraph below.

This is the result of running my code:

[image]

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

I could just add these all in at the end of the report manually as I have with this, but it would be good to make this directly in LaTeX.

Comment: the `fit` tikzlibrary should do it -- a search on the site will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using functionality in feynmf but it does use some of the more odd/complicated functionality.

The trick is to use the `\fmfforce` command to manually specify where you want the corners of the box to be relative to other points and directions in the diagram.

Specifically each of the corners is set to be offset from one of the vertices by a specified fraction of the vertical gap between the two inputs (0.3*) and a specified fraction of the horizontal gap between the two vertices we want the box around (+/-0.1*).

The vloc function is the underlying function to get the coordinates for a node in our graph and the __ are required to be added in front of any vertex name when referring to it in the vloc command. There are many other functions and operations you can do in the fmfforce command but they are not needed here.

```
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(200,60)
            \fmfleft{i1,i2}
            \fmfright{f1,f2}
            \fmf{vanilla}{i1,v1}
            \fmf{vanilla}{i2,v1}
            \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v1,v2}
            \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v2,v1}
            \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v2,v3}
            \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v3,v2}
            \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v3,v4}
            \fmf{vanilla,left=0.6,tension=0.4}{v4,v3}
            \fmf{vanilla}{v4,f1}
            \fmf{vanilla}{v4,f2}
            \fmffreeze
            \fmfforce{vloc(__v1)+0.3*(vloc(__i2)-vloc(__i1))+0.1*(vloc(__v1)-vloc(__v2))}{b1}
            \fmfforce{vloc(__v1)-0.3*(vloc(__i2)-vloc(__i1))+0.1*(vloc(__v1)-vloc(__v2))}{b2}
            \fmfforce{vloc(__v2)-0.3*(vloc(__i2)-vloc(__i1))-0.1*(vloc(__v1)-vloc(__v2))}{b3}
            \fmfforce{vloc(__v2)+0.3*(vloc(__i2)-vloc(__i1))-0.1*(vloc(__v1)-vloc(__v2))}{b4}
            \fmf{dashes}{b1,b2,b3,b4,b1}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
```

[image: Feynman Diagram]

Comment: That is exactly what I want, cheers mate <3